# ASP Identity role is not saved into the database However the Identity user is saved

Tags: asp.net-core

`result = await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));`

I tried

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

after adding a role but the server message given duplicated role inserted.???!!!

Comment: could you pls show us more codes so that we can try to reproduce the issue ? or did you follow any tutorial to do that? I used [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) before and it worked well for me.

Comment: Thank you for trying to assist. Yes, I used the same toturial. Unfortunately, the tool I used to view the database mdf file is called systools. The said tool is not showing data in aspnetroles and aspnetusersrole tables. However, it shows data in asptnet users. The data is inserted into DB succesfully, but the tool used is incompatible with the version if mdf file.

Comment: I also followed the tutorial to do a test yesterday, after I run `Update-Database`, I have the tables in the database, but there's no user. After I run the app and register a user, there would be a new user appear in the user table, but no role in rule table. Roles are used for authorization, and we need to follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to use it.

Comment: Yes exactly, if you need any help  just let me know.

Comment: you mentioned `given duplicated role inserted`, so could you pls let us know if the role existed in the database?

Comment: The server message is clearly told that a violation is taken place as the role is already exist. 
The probem was the systool (mdf file viewer) did not show any data in aspnetrole nor  in aspnetuserrole due to incompatability.

Comment: look like issue is related to `systool `?

Comment: Exactly. Try to install the free version of systool.